# Guice/Morphia, AssistedInjection error

Tags: java, guice, morphia

(or maybe incorrect usage? I am new to Guice)
I get the following errors:

- String cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.
- java.lang.Class T cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.

I have the following:

```
public interface BaseRepository<T, PK> (){
    public void f1();
}

public class BaseRepositoryMongoImpl<T, String> extends BaseDAO<T, String> implements BaseRepository<T, String> {
    @Inject
    BaseRepositoryMongoImpl(MongoClient mongoClient, Morphia morphia,
        String dbName, @Assisted Class<T> type) {
        super(type, mongoClient, morphia, (java.lang.String) dbName);
    }

    public void f1(){}
}
```

Factory interface and class

```
public interface BaseRepositoryFactory {
    public BaseRepository create(Class<?> tableClass);
}

public class BaseRepositoryFactoryImpl implements BaseRepositoryFactory {

    private final MongoClientProvider mongoClientProvider;
    private final MorphiaProvider morphiaProvider;

    @Inject
    public BaseRepositoryFactoryImpl(MongoClientProvider mongoClientProvider,
        MorphiaProvider morphiaProvider) {
        this.mongoClientProvider = mongoClientProvider;
        this.morphiaProvider = morphiaProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public BaseRepository create(Class<?> tableClass) {
        return new BaseRepositoryMongoDBImpl(mongoClientProvider.get(),
                morphiaProvider.get(),
                "DATABASE_NAME", //comes from properties
                tableClass);
    }
}
```

Provider classes

```
public class MongoClientProvider implements Provider<MongoClient> {

    @Override
    public MongoClient get() {
        MongoClient mongoClient = null;
        try {
            //for sake of simplicity, all properties code is removed
            //the database name is part of the properties
            mongoClient = new MongoClient("DATABASE_HOST");
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Logger.error("Severe Error: Unknown database host", ex);
        }

        return mongoClient;
    }
}

public class MorphiaProvider implements Provider<Morphia> {
    @Override
    public Morphia get() {
        Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
        //for sake of simplicity, all properties code is removed
        //the package name is part of the properties
        morphia.mapPackage("MODEL_PACKAGE", true); 
        return morphia;
    }
}
```

Finally the module class

```
public class DatabaseModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
                .implement(BaseRepository.class, BaseRepositoryMongoDBImpl.class)
                .build(BaseRepositoryFactory.class));
    }
}
```

Do I need to anything with TypeLiteral in the module class?

Also, can I declare the BaseRepositoryFactory variable as

```
@Inject
private static BaseRepositoryFactory baseRepo;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**First:** You cannot inject a plain String, guice just cannot know what you want injected. Use a qualifier to specify what you need. Simplest modifier: @Named.

So:

```
@Inject
@Named("foo")
private String myString;

@Provides
@Named("foo")
public String myString() {
   return ... whatever myString should be ... constant? property? DB value?
}
```

**Second:** your assisted inject approach is not the "guicy" way. Check out the [assisted inject extension](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject), you do not have to implement the interfaces yourself:

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
 .implement(Payment.class, RealPayment.class)
 .build(PaymentFactory.class));
```

That way, you can get rid of some code, which makes searching the real problem a lot easier.

**Third:** You can use [requestStaticInjection()](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#static-injections), but normally you shouldn't do that. The concepts of dependency injection and static value holders do not match, you get a whole lot of trouble, just use singleton bindings instead.

Comment: Jan, thanks for the response. For no 1: I am assuming you mean the string with the dbName. I tried moving that to be an assisted parameter but looks like a problem, let me debug further. On no 2 - both Morphia and MongoClient require parameters for creation hence I created custom providers for them. Let me review no 3, but after an initial glance I agree it is not something I'd should do.